# Every row inserted updates timestamp to current date/time for all rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Sorry, i'm new to this and my knowledge is limited. I have a have webform that captures information. I have a create_date column to add the current date/time stamp however every time it captures an entry it updates all rows. How can I setup this up to log when the record was created?

[image: column details]

[image: all rows update to most current entry]

Comment: Computed columns are computed during *retrieval* (they don't normally have any storage space to store their value, and when they do, you can't set them equal to something non-deterministic like `getdate()`)

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's a computed column. You should change that into a regular column with the default value of `GetDate()`.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
    DROP COLUMN create_date;

ALTER TABLE TableName
    ADD COLUMN create_date NOT NULL DEFAULT(GetDate());
```

Please note that by doing that, you will re-create the `create_date` column and all the records existing in the table when the column is created will get the same value. It will only be an accurate create_date for records inserted after it was re-created.

Answer (score 0):

Though its recommended to use Default for this scenario, its not necessarily wrong to use a computed column. If your specific case demands for a computed column instead of `DEFAULT`, try making it `PERSISTED` as shown in the blog post below.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1682/using-computed-columns-in-sql-server-with-persisted-values/

**EDIT:**

My bad, @ZoharPeled is correct in his comment about `GETDATE` being non-deterministic. `PERSISTED` will not work in this case. `DEFAULT` seems to be the best option.

Comment: You cannot make a persisted computed column when it's based on `GetDate()`, since `GetDate()` is non-deterministic.